# Login for Google Cloud Endpoints portal page without Google account

Tags: firebase, authentication, google-cloud-platform, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-endpoints

I have found the tutorial [Using Firebase to authenticate users](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/authenticating-users-firebase) that explains how to authenticate users with Firebase to access different services.

However I haven't found how to enable Firebase login for the whole Google Cloud Endpoints portal page (like for example https://endpointsportal.ourproject.cloud.goog/).

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the only identity supported today is GCP meaning Cloud Endpoints Portal doesn't support 3rd party sign in. You can use Firebase to authenticate against the API, but not to log into the portal.